# Assign a variable to each row from one query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

How do I assign a variable to each row from the 4 rows created by this query below? (laravel, Eloquent/Fluent)

```
 $topics = SubjectUser::where('user_id', 8)
        ->join('subjectlists', 'subjectlists.id', '=','subjectlists_user.subjectlist_id')
        ->select('subjectlists.name', 'subjectlists.title1')->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(4)->get();
```

or if any one knows a way of retrieving 4 random separate rows without duplicates that would also help. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Ideally I would like to return this to my view

```
return View::make('subjects', compact(array('firstrow', 
                   'secondrow', 'thirdrow', 'fourthrow')));
```

So that I can something like this in my view

```
{{$firstrow->name}}   {{$firstrow->title1}}
```

Above is just an example and so in real life I have a high number of columns which is the reason why I'm looking for an elegant way of solving this problem.

Comment: I'm guessing I use some kind of while loop in php but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will return a collection of models. You can simply convert it into an array and then set the keys with `array_combine()`

```
$topics = SubjectUser::where('user_id', 8)
        ->join('subjectlists', 'subjectlists.id', '=','subjectlists_user.subjectlist_id')
        ->select('subjectlists.name', 'subjectlists.title1')->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(4)->get();

$topics = $topics->all();
$variableNames = ['firstrow', 'secondrow', 'thirdrow', 'fourthrow'];
$viewVariables = array_combine($variableNames, $topics);

return View::make('subjects', $viewVariables);
```

Comment: The reason why I want a separate the rows is so that I dont have to bring in so many variables to the view(blade). For example from my code above the `subjectlists.name` and `subjectlists.title1` is in the same row and so I was hoping to assign just one variable. This is just an example but in real life I have multiple column names to take to the view so you can imagine the amount of variables I need to take through.

Comment: Then how would you access the contents of that variable in the view? I'm a bit confused because variables can only hold one value.

Comment: One variable actually holds an array of values. Im unsure if you've used laravel but in the view you access the value of the key value pairs. So from my example above using one variable I can just write `{{$variable->name}}` or `{{$variable->title1}}` in my view.

Comment: Believe me, I'm very used to Laravel. Also that's an object not an array and technically its *one* value of a variable. Anyways.. back to the question. So how do you now want to have that 4 rows accessible in your view? Maybe you could add the view code (how you'd like it to look like) to your question?

Comment: sorry mate im new to this so im not used to the terminology as of yet ;). Anyway I've edited my question.

Comment: Ahh I see. Now I get it... Updated my answer :)

Comment: and so what would I type in my view because I cant get any of the variables that you've suggested to work in blade

Comment: I made a small mistake..It's `all()` not `toArray()` after that correction you should be able to use it like you wanted

Answer (score 0):

It's awkward but if you need to save each row in a variable the double dollar sign is probably what you want:

```
$var = "value";   // variable is $var
$$var = "other value"; // variable is $value
```

Each row will create a new variable that is set to something unique about that row like the id value.  Psuedocode example:

```
foreach($topics as $t) {
    $id = $t.id
    $$id = $t
}
```